# Run script in Repeater and display result

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater on my page which I wan to run a piece of script specific to each item.

This is my code so far

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="topicView" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table width="925px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left;" class="topic-header-home"><strong>Topic Title</strong></td>
                <td width="10%" class="topic-header-home"><strong>Posts</strong></td>
                <td width="20%" class="topic-header-home"><strong>Started By</strong></td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>        
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;" class="topic-cont-home">
                <p><a href='view.aspx?topicID=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TopicID")%>'><strong><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TopicName")%></strong></a></p>
            </td>
            <td class="topic-cont-home">
                <script type="text/C#">
                    // Define the select statement.
                    // All information is needed
                    string selectPostCount = "select count(*) from Posts WHERE TopicID=@topicID";
                    // Define the ADO.NET Objects
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        SqlCommand pccmd = new SqlCommand(selectPostCount, con);
                        pccmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topicID", <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TopicID")%>);
                        con.Open();
                        int numrows = (int)pccmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        string posts = numrows.ToString();
                        con.Close();
                        posts.InnerHTML = posts;
                    }
                </script>
                <p id="posts" runat="server"></p>
            </td>
            <td class="topic-cont-home">
                <p><strong><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Username")%></strong></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Can anyone tell me how I would get this to work?

So far it isn't coming up saying I have any errors, but it's not working either.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the script block in a protected method  in your codebehind and just do: GetNumberOfRows will be defined in the code behind

```
   <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <p id="posts" runat="server"><%#GetNumberOfRows((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TopicID"))%></p>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>

protected int GetNumberOfRows(int topicId)
    {
       //Run query and return result

    }
```

Comment: This is in a repeater so would that work? Sorry I'm a visual learner. Would it be possible to post a code example for the cs in C#?

Comment: Thanks. But since it's in a repeater it will not write to the id as it "can't find it in the context". this is my cs code http://pastebin.com/0r2QRLbF

Comment: Hi. I meant to return the value from the c# method, not assign it to the markup :-) If you return the count it will be rendered in the Markup

Comment: On a side note. It's possible to do what you're doing, but I would recommend an approach where you build your entire data source up front (including the counts). That way you don't need to call the database for every row in your repeater...

Comment: I have edited my files now to reflect the return (http://pastebin.com/0r2QRLbF) but now I'm getting an error "Specified cast is not valid". Any ideas? I've never used return before

Comment: `<%#GetNumberOfRows((int)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TopicID"))%>` needed to be `<%#GetNumberOfRows(Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "TopicID")))%>`. Thanks for all your help!